# Change color of options in overflow button?

Tags: android, layout

I have been having an issue where my overflow settings [button appears black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUnlB.jpg) and makes the text difficult to read. I instead want the settings button to appear [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4mtM.png) as that is how it shows up in my menu.xml

I have tried searching for a solution but most of them are how to change the color of the three dots and not of the actual options. Any help solving the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using a light theme? like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Yeah that fixed the issue. I had my toolbar style set to dark instead of light. Thanks